# inner anchor scrolling with wordpress

Tags: jquery, links

i got this page:
http://www.amirwebdeveloper.com/blog/common-sense-sensibility-and-accessibility-or-how-not-to-drive-the-surfer-mad-guide

im trying to make a inner page anchor:

```
<a href="#topic1">....</a>

content

<a name="#topic1">topic 1</a>
bla bla
```

for some reason it not scrolls.. anyone have a fix for it?

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor should point to an element with an id, e.g.

```
<a href="#topic1">....</a>
```

content

```
<h3 id="topic1">....</h3>
```

Otherwise the anchor doesn't have somewhere to point to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should point out that in the WordPress visual editor, there is no option to add an anchor point, and thus you should use something like the Tiny MCE Advanced plugin, which allows you to add the anchor point id.